# ASP.NET MVC: Problema ao atribuir valor decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, decimal

FichaViewModel.cs

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A altura é obrigatória.")]
public decimal Altura { get; set; }
```

ficha.js

```
$("#Altura").mask("9.99");
```

FichaController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastro(FichaViewModel fichaView)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       ...
    }

    return View(fichaView);
 }
```

> O valor '1.70' não é válido para Altura.

Como faço para a Altura aceitar o valor passado?

---

Ao deixar a máscara com vírgula (9,99) a validação reconhece como texto, e com ponto (9.99) dá o erro como mencionei. Então resolvi deixar a property como string e ao fazer o mapeamento da FichaViewModel para FichaDomain, com o AutoMapper, ocorre a conversão normalmente.

Comment: Rafael, há um tempo atrás fiz essa pergunta: [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211/qual-a-forma-correta-de-usar-os-tipos-float-double-e-decimal)

Comment: Olá @Marconi! Então, já testei double também, mas o problema é o mesmo.

Comment: Verifica se a variável `fichaView`está recebendo a `Altura` certinho.

Comment: Ela recebe o valor 0, mas quando vou ver nos erros do ModelState, a mensagem que da é a que mencionei.